# Problem with variable scope in nested Backbone views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I have a parent view which contains a Backgrid view.  In the parent view's initialize section I define a variable isWellSelected.  The variable is toggled in the Backgrid column logic when a tickbox is checked.  I am able to watch the variable toggled when a box is ticked and unticked.

However, once an event fires the variable is no longer in scope for the event to see.   I suspect I may need to pass the variable to the Backrgrid view but I am unsure how to do that correctly.  Please advise.

```
app.wellCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#wellTemplate').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.isWellSelected = false;

        // isWellSelected toggled to true when a tickbox is checked in the columns block.
        var columns = [...];

        // instantiate collection
        var wellCollection = new app.wellCollection;

        // Set up a grid view to use the pageable collection
        var wellGrid = new Backgrid.Grid({
            columns: columns,
            collection: wellCollection
        });

        // Initialize the paginator
        var paginator = new Backgrid.Extension.Paginator({
            collection: wellCollection
        });

        // Render the template
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        // Render the grid
        this.$el.append(wellGrid.render().el);
        this.$el.append(paginator.render().$el);

        wellCollection.fetch({reset: true}).then(function () {...});
    },

    events: {
        'click #EvaluateWell': function(){
            this.evalWell(event, this.isWellSelected);
            console.log("In events - isWellSelected: " + this.isWellSelected);}
    },

    // More stuff
}
```

Constructive feedback welcome.

Thanks!

Adding a snippet for "columns" as per JT's request:

```
var columns = [
{
    name: '',
    label: 'Select',
    cell: Backgrid.BooleanCell.extend({
        events : {
            'change': function(ev){
                var $checkbox = $(ev.target);
                var $checkboxes = $('.backgrid input[type=checkbox]');

                if($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                    $checkboxes.attr("disabled", true);
                    this.isWellSelected = true;

                    // Disable all checkboxes but this one
                    $checkbox.removeAttr("disabled");
                } else {
                    // Enable all checkboxes again
                    $checkboxes.removeAttr("disabled");
                    this.isWellSelected = false;
                }
            }
        }
    })
}, {
    name: "api",
    label: "API",
    editable: false, // Display only!
    cell: "string"
}, {
    name: "company",
    label: "Operator",
    editable: false, // Display only!
    cell: "string"
}];
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, shouldn't `var isWellSelected = false;` be `this.isWellSelected = false;` because otherwise you can only access it inside `initialize` method...

Comment: @TJ  That is what was needed.  However, then `this.isWellSelected` is not getting passed to the function bound to the event correctly.  It is always false.  Also, why is it not `var this.wellSelected` ?

Comment: no need of `var` because you are not creating a variable, you're creating a property on the view instance with `this.something =`, so that you can access it in other view methods (You can create variables in global/broader scopes outside the view but it's a bad practice). Where is the code that is setting it to true? Can you share it?

Comment: Ah!  That makes sense.  I thought I had a decent handle on scope and closures but I guess I had better refresh.  I'll see if I cannot reduce the code down enough for posting.  It is in the column object for BackGrid.

Comment: @TJ  I added a snippet from the column object where the value in question is toggled.

Comment: There is a very high chance that the context is different in the `change` event callback, by that I mean `this` is referring to something else, not `wellCollectionView`. You can confirm this buy putting a breakpoint and inspecting value of  `this`. You need to have a reference to the view instance inside the callback to change the property value on it.
something like `app.WellCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({});  app.wellCollectionView = new app.WellCollectionView(); //later app.wellCollectionView.isWellSelected = true;`

Comment: @TJ  Much obliged.  The fully qualified view name on the property is a tad ugly but I'll have another go using that format.  If that works, it means I will need to figure out how to pass the view `this` into the callback to prevent tight coupling in the event it is refactored to another scope.

Comment: Once you got things working, you can prob improve code with something like this `'change': function(ev){ // here this will refer to view instance due to bind}.bind(app.wellCollectionView)` see [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). Or maybe just pass a reference to `Backgrid` with a shorter name (I'm not familiar with Backgrid)

Comment: @TJ `app.wellCollectionView.isWellSelected = true;` does not work either.  I think I may need to figure out how to pass the view property into backgrid for it to work correctly.  BackGrid is fairly popular so I will look for examples.  Someone has to have done this before.